# PHP Cannot access property value of an object using json_decode

Tags: javascript, php

So I have 2 php files, let's call it UploadImages.php and Caller.php

so in the UploadImages.php I have a function like so

```
<?php
 function UploadImages(){
   $result = [
     "UploadOk" => 0,
     "UploadMsg" => "Upload successful" ];

   echo(json_encode($result));
 }
?>
```

and this is how I handle it in the Caller.php

```
<?php
  include "UploadImages.php";

  $uploadResult = json_decode(UploadImages(), true);

  if($uploadResult["UploadOk"] == 1) {
     // do something else
  }
  else {
     echo $uploadResult["UploadMsg"];
  }
?>
```

using ajax from javascript, I have this result:

```
"{"UploadOk":1,"UploadMsg":"Upload successful"}"
```

what i expected is only UploadMsg property instead it returns an object, note that I actually need to process the UploadOk in the Caller.php instead of just dumping a whole object to javascript, so the JSON.parse method in javascript would not be the correct way to handle this situation.

Comment: This  `$result = [
     "UploadOk" => 0,
     "UploadMsg" => "Upload successful" ];` is an array, not a Json object

Comment: You need to return the value rather than echo it for you second script to work

Comment: You are *`echo`ing* the JSON, not ***`return`ing*** it as you seem to want.

Comment: `UploadImages()` doesn't return anything, consequently `json_decode(UploadImages(), true)` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @deceze I like how you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` inside `UploadImages` returns the object, As PHP `echo` send response headers,  thus calling via ajax you get the response from this method.

Change the method with following and then try:

```
function UploadImages(){
   $result = [
     "UploadOk" => 0,
     "UploadMsg" => "Upload successful" ];
    return json_encode($result);
 }
```

Note: Also you don't need to use `json_encode` inside `UploadImages` just return the the array as follow:

```
function UploadImages(){
   $result = [
     "UploadOk" => 0,
     "UploadMsg" => "Upload successful" ];
    return $result;
 }
```

and in Caller.php

```
<?php
  include "UploadImages.php";

  $uploadResult = UploadImages();

  if($uploadResult["UploadOk"] == 1) {
     // do something else
  }
  else {
     echo $uploadResult["UploadMsg"];
  }
?>
```